# Stop drag-n-drop event with Raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, dom-events, raphael

I am trying to simulate the swipe event from the iPhone with Raphaeljs.
To do so, I am using the drag and drop event.

To simulate the event in have a method in the move event that calculate the distance between my object and the mouse position. If the mouse goes after that distance I want to stop the drag and drop event. This is where I'm stuck.

Here is the code:

```
var start = function (event) {
  },
  move = function (event) {
   inrange = self.inRange (circle.attr("cx"), circle.attr("cy"), event.pageX, event.pageY); 
      if(inrange == false){
         //Stop draging!
      }
   
  },
  up = function () {
    circle.animate({ r: 40, "stroke-width": 1 }, 200);
  };
  circle.drag(move, start, up);
```

In the move method I need the stop the drag event or simulate a `mouseup`. How can I do so?

Comment: You're trying to immediately stop the `circle` from being dragged any further - correct?

Comment: Do you mind putting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your current code?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/9v2Rs/

Comment: Hm, I can't say I understand what that's supposed to do vs. what it's doing right now.

Comment: I've added a few lines. On the unrange conditions it has to stop the move event because in my real code I calculate stuff from the last position of the mouse.

Comment: Then you're probably better off just saving the mouse position that you're actually interested in (to, say, global scope) so you can access it later. You definitely can't control the mouse with JavaScript.

Comment: I know, i could try to trigger the mouseup event or your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gregory You can use a JS closure to detect if the circle needs to stop dragging. And @apphacker there is a [known issue](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/199) in Raphael that prevents undrag from working. It is scheduled to be fixed in 2.0, but that doesn't have a release date as of yet (and the bug isn't fixed in the beta code, despite the ticket saying it is.

I recommend manually implementing the mousedown, mouseup and mousemove events using jQuery, as per @floyd's recommendation, and add a JS closure check in your move function to see if the circle needs to stop being dragged yet or not.'

It also occurs to me that your original post was last edited in Nov '10, so you might have moved on since then ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#events):

> To unbind events use the same method names with “un” prefix, i.e. element.unclick(f);

and

> To unbind drag use the undrag method.

So I would think `circle.undrag();` should work.

Comment: I've already looked at the documentation and i've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, to @Gregory's comment. This will stop future drag event firing. This will not cause the current drag to stop.

Comment: What about event.preventDefault() maybe that prevents the the item from moving further and the user will give up the drag.

Comment: @apphacker see my answer - there is a known bug with undrag in Raphael

Answer (score 0):

If you can include jQuery you can use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on "mouseup."  If you can't include jQuery maybe just take a look at the source and lift that one function?

**UPDATE**

After some brief googling I came across this implementation.  Only tested in in Chrome though:

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
  if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
  } else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}
```